# How to read a .tar.gz file in into a buffer in C++

Tags: c++, qt

I want to read a .tar.gz files contents into a byte buffer.

I don't want to make a system call "tar" because the program should be multiplatform so it should be a universal solution.

The real case is there is a .tar.gz file containing multiple .tar.gz files, and each of them contains multiple files.

I want to be able to seperate those final files like `std::vector<std::vector<uint_8t>>`

The outer vector will indicate the final files, and the inner vector will store the bytes.

Comment: The code for both tar and gzip is open source.

Comment: C++ does not have this ability built in. You'll need to find a library that can load .tar.gz files.

Comment: BTW, `tar` is not a system call.

Comment: @Friedrich I assume they mean "making a `std::system` call"

Comment: @AlanBirtles I agree that's probably what they meant but it's not what they *wrote*. I think the correct use of technical terms is important. In hindsight, my comment could have been more helpful, pointing out how `tar` is a utility program etc.

Answer (score -2):

There are many open sourced compression library, such as zlib(https://github.com/madler/zlib), zippp(https://github.com/LoganTutt/zippp) and so on.
You can import those third party library to your project to achieve your goals.

Comment: zippp is an iterator library, not for reading zip files. Zlib will help with reading gz files but you'd need something else to read the contained tar file